# Undifined reference to espeak-ng headers in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, error-handling, undefined-reference, espeak

I have downloaded `espeak-ng 1.1.49` and `./configure make make install` it, and tested it by `espeak --stdout "this is a test" | paplay` successfully and it worked. Then I tried to use it inside my C++ code(testSpeak.cpp) that I found on the internet as you can see below:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <vector> 
#include </usr/local/include/espeak-ng/speak_lib.h> 

int samplerate; // determined by espeak, will be in Hertz (Hz)
const int buflength = 200; // passed to espeak, in milliseconds (ms)

std::vector<short> sounddata;

int SynthCallback(short *wav, int numsamples, espeak_EVENT *events) {
    if (wav == NULL)
        return 1; // NULL means done.

    /* process your samples here, let's just gather them */
    sounddata.insert(sounddata.end(), wav, wav + numsamples);
    return 0; // 0 continues synthesis, 1 aborts 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    char text[] = {"my name is espeak"};
    samplerate = espeak_Initialize(AUDIO_OUTPUT_RETRIEVAL, buflength, NULL, 0);
    espeak_SetSynthCallback(&SynthCallback);
    espeak_SetVoiceByName("en"); 
    unsigned int flags=espeakCHARS_AUTO | espeakENDPAUSE;
    size_t size = strlen(text); 
    espeak_Synth(text, size + 1, 0, POS_CHARACTER, 0, flags, NULL, NULL); 
    espeak_Synchronize();

    /* in theory sounddata holds your samples now... */

    return 0; 
}
```

But after trying to make executable by this command: `g++ testSpeak.cpp -o speaks` I got these error messages:

```
/tmp/ccR9O0vw.o: In function `main':
testSpeak.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `espeak_Initialize'
testSpeak.cpp:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `espeak_SetSynthCallback'
testSpeak.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `espeak_SetVoiceByName'
testSpeak.cpp:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `espeak_Synth'
testSpeak.cpp:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `espeak_Synchronize'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know the problem is about linking but as I am new to Linux, don't know how can I fix it! Also I searched a lot but couldn't understand the solutions :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to compile correctly try installing

```
sudo apt-get install espeak-data libespeak-dev espeak-ng
```

your include is

```
   #include </usr/local/include/espeak-ng/speak_lib.h>
```

make it

```
   #include <espeak-ng/speak_lib.h>
```

your compile command is

```
g++ testSpeak.cpp -o speaks
```

try this one instead

```
g++ -W -o speaks myEspeak.cpp -lespeak
```

reference from i wouldn't compile it tough tried and it doesn't work probably an old version but with the code you provided and installing those programs and changing out your include your code will compile. I doesn't do much I would find a way to store that into a a .wav file.

```
http://apexlogic.net/code-bank/c-2/espeak-basic-usage-example/
```

when ever you compile from a shared library you need to link it with something that looks like

```
 -lespeak
```

Comment: Hi dear, I faced a new program here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400061/speaks-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libespeak-ng-so-1-cannot-open-s  . may you help me there?